# c# store locally a password used for online verification

Tags: c#, winforms, passwords

I am wondering what would be the best way to go about this. Basically my program will be behaving like the Steam application for PCs, or Spotify which automatically login in the user.

In other words, the user has an online account created on our website. With this account login (email and password), they can log into our c# app and have access to the program's features.

I have this working fine, as the c# app connects securely over the internet to a web service armed with SSL which accesses website's database and verifies the login info. I would like this step to be automated, so as soon as they launch the program, it should auto-log them in provided they have logged in at least once before.

What would be the best way to do this and not compromise the security of their login info?

Comment: The problem with any auto-login scheme from a security standpoint is, if another person (not your verified user) tries to access the application from your user's computer, it will let them in even though they may not be acting with the verified user's permission or on their behalf. If you truly want to protect the verified user's information, do not implement auto-login.

Comment: Because of the nature of my program, there are actually two logins. First is the site account, and after is the local database user. So even if someone who isn't meant to be using the program attempts to login, even with the auto login at the first step, they still need the database user password after.

Comment: Your concern is a valid one of course, but I think in my case it's not a problem. And since I have this double login system, that's another reason to go for auto login as it will remove one step for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a db table , lets say its called userlogged.
Create a GUID every time the user successfully logs in. Store that GUID in userlogged and return it to your c# app so it can be stored locally (you can encript it, use windows registry(regedit) or whatever you want to make it harder for anyone to copy it).

Next time if the GUID is stored locally, that will be send to your application and your application will log the user, and create a new GUID that also will be sent to store locally (with this, in case someone copies the GUID there wont be 2 users logged at the same time).

If logging failed, delete the GUID from the database.

Also set a flag so if a user has been logged from the GUID he will be asked to log again for some security related operations like change the password.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you wanted to securely store the user id and password. And use them to login when the application started.

There are 2 parts to it

1. Storage - Where to keep these data
2. Security - How to protect the password
3. Many locations you can keep these information. Application Configuration file, Registry, INI, local storage, db etc. I'll leave this to your decision.
4. This is the critical part, protecting the password. You can use Triple DES or AES encryptions to secure the password. Or alternatively you can use Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI), which uses operating system generated and protected keys and the Triple DES encryption algorithm to encrypt and decrypt information. In c#, you can use System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData class for this matter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will it be a concern if this encrypted password is visible to the user? Or any other user that snoops on the computer? Assuming I store it in the registry, since this is where I store the email already, is there any way this encrypted string can be reversed?

Comment: With the right encryption method, will be tough to anyone to decrypt them.

Comment: Ok i will look into that. Thanks!